# How to get Heroku to detect GO buildpack

Tags: git, heroku, go, push, buildpack

In attempting to deploy my own GO app using `git push heroku master` I get the error `Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/go`

Because the error is quite specific about failure to detect a buildpack I tried manually setting it with the command `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/go`
The response however was `! Thebuildpack heroku/go is already set on your app.`

Despite this push attempts continue to produce the same error `Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/go`

It seems like the error message is leading me astray, what else might be wrong? Following my research here, I made sure that there is a Procfile in the app folder and I was able to successfully follow all the steps for deploying the Heroku GO example beforehand.

Comment: Procfile contents? What does the root of your git repo look like?

Comment: Procfile contains `web: gweet` rest of repo as per:[link](https://github.com/skorokithakis/gweet)

Answer (score 6):

According to [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-support), the go buildpack requires [Godep](https://github.com/tools/godep) in order to know how to build and deploy your app.

Do a `godep save` and commit that before pushing to Heroku.

Comment: Thanks @David, that's firmly pointed me in the right direction but now I've go to work out what the GO "vendoring  experiment" flag is about because `godep save -r ./...` is complaining about it.

Comment: Do you have Go 1.6 and the latest godep?

Comment: Hi @elithrar, yes Go 1.6 and latest godep.

Comment: vendor experiment was for 1.5, if you are on 1.6, just do "godep save" it will create Godeps/Godeps.json (this is what heroku keys off of)  and a vendor/... tree of your external dependencies.  Which is a good practice so you don't get surprise library upgrades on a heroku deploy.

Comment: also, probably dont want to use -r, re-writing the imports will just make future upgrades harder.  that's probably why it is complaining